# changing session variable not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include 'cardclass.php';
    $cards = new deck();
    $cards = unserialize($_SESSION['cards']);

    $cards->drawCard();
    $cards->pushBack();

    $_SESSION['cards'] = serialize($cards);

    exit();

?>
```

I have a php page that creates a deck then shuffles then stores in session. Now i have this code which gets the session object draws a card and puts the card to the back of the deck then save to session. now when i call this 4 times i get "4 hearts 4 hearts 4 hearts 4 hearts" instead of 4 different cards. i believe its because its not saving the session correctly.

EDIT:

```
function dealCard(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;    

            }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","dealcard.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

i have a feeling this has something to do with it

Comment: `$cards = new deck(); $cards = unserialize($_SESSION['cards']);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function dealCard(){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","dealcard.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;    

}
```

changed my js function to this and it works now. the async was messing with it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything here that could affect the session handling, are you sure the deck class works as wanted?
Try to run drawCard() and pushBack() multiple times in a single PHP script and check the results.

Edit: Below this line isn't relevant anymore as he deleted his answer.

What knizhnikov said in his answer doesn't seem to apply here, changes in the session variable gets saved on server-side after the PHP script is completed. You would only get issues if you'd run session_start() after you've sent output because that function needs to send a cookie header.